# Aside from the Bridge set pieces, which Star Trek TOS structural interior set piece garnered the most onscreen time?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, props

Aside from the Bridge(and it's possible there was a set piece in the Bridge ensemble that qualifies because it appeared outside of the Bridge) set pieces, which Star Trek TOS structural interior set piece garnered the most onscreen time? For instance, was there a specific door or wall panel, or corridor or ? that had substainaly more air time as the crew scurried about the Enterprise than any of the other Enterprise set piece interior props? Which set piece was it?

Comment: One would guess, the Transporter pad.

Comment: I would guess that the transporter room would have had the most appearances after the bridge, but the corridors or sickbay would have had more overall screen time. Mostly, dunno.

Comment: @Major What are your thoughts on tagging questions like this with [tag:star-trek]? Last time I checked, there was a weak consensus in favor of tagging everything Star Trek-related with [tag:star-trek], but I get the feeling that you aren’t in favor of that.

Comment: @armadillo : The consensus is that it should have the tag.  I'm making a star-trek gold status executive decision and adding the tag.  :-)

Comment: @Praxis Make it so.

Answer (score 6):

## Turbolift(s)

I'm going to go out in a limb and say the **turbolifts**, of which there was only one such set piece, which stood in as the various Enterprise turbolifts.

Turbolifts are frequently seen on-screen in *TOS* episodes.

[image]

Comment: Your original answer was about TNG and you edited it to be TOS, but is it still true in TOS that we frequently see conversations in turbolifts or that they are paused for longer conversations? Having just watched season 1 I remember hardly any conversations on turbolifts, and no instances of pausing.

Comment: @Hypnosifl : Wasn't done editing.

Comment: @Hypnosifl : I do think you are correct, about the conversations / pausing.

Comment: Sick bay? That's I'm a few scenes

Answer (score 5):

It would be difficult to say with any confidence without going through and timing each scene, but having recently rewatched season 1, my guess would be the set for crew quarters (usually Kirk's), which often featured in extended dialogue scenes in many episodes. If you google "quarters" along with site:www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek you can find a large number of episodes whose transcripts mention that some scene is set in someone's quarters...some are animated series episodes, but you can add -animated to the search, and the [search results](http://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=site:www.chakoteya.net%2FStarTrek%20%22quarters%22%20-animated) show 44 transcripts.

[image]

For "turbolift" there are [31 results](http://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=site:www.chakoteya.net%2FStarTrek%20%22turbolift%22%20-animated), but looking over some of the examples and doing control-F (or command-F on a Mac) to search for where in the transcript the word appears, the dialogue scenes set on them usually appear pretty short, while the ones in quarters are often longer. For "transporter room" you get [59 results](http://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=site:www.chakoteya.net%2FStarTrek%20%22transporter%20room%22%20-animated), but searching those transcripts there seem to be a lot that just feature Kirk on the bridge giving an order to the transporter room (only if the transcript features [transporter room] in brackets is there an actual scene there), and when there are scenes they again seem to usually be pretty brief. For "sickbay" there are [44 results](http://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=site:www.chakoteya.net%2FStarTrek%20%22sickbay%22%20-animated), though again there are a good number where sickbay is just mentioned in dialogue rather than a scene being set there...when there are scenes there my impression is that they're likely to be longer than typical scenes set in the transporter room or turbolift though, so my guess is this would be the second most likely candidate for the non-bridge set having the most airtime.

Comment: http://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/inconsistencies/reused_props_misc.htm

Comment: http://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/inconsistencies/reused_ship_interiors.htm

Comment: Not to mention that Yeoman Rand or lightly clad female passengers seemed to show up frequently when the scene was his quarters. I always had that expectation.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the most filmed section of the ship, The corridor
[image]